# How can Set Current currency in paypal in magento?

Tags: magento

When i select paypal in payement method then its pass base currency which is selected in admin panel. But i want pass current currency ,selected in front site.

I know Midify paypal Api, But were and which file want to changes, please describe briefly.

So any body know then please help me.

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: What is the purpose of such changes? Don't you think that it may cause loosing some money on each transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the paypal api and change the value that are sent to paypal and you probably will need to override other methods that are validating the sums that are paid.

```
$ grep getBaseGran app/code/core/Mage/Paypal -rsn
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php:180: $this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal(),

app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php:246: $this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal())

app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php:283: if (Mage::helper('paypal')->areCartLineItemsValid($items, $totals, $this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal())) {

app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php:147: $grandTotal = $order->getBaseGrandTotal();
```

Comment: Hi 
Anton S,
Thanks for Reply me,
i Have understand to modify paypal API , but which file and which type changes is required please specify in Briefly.

Any Body know then please reply me.

Thanks,
VIJAY

Comment: well you have to look up where the variables get set for request and extend those classes . I edited my answer to give you better hints where to start digging

Comment: Hi Anton S,
Thanks again for reply me , But i am not understand again, so please help me, you are describe that want change, But replace what ? for pass current currency not Base currency.
Please Help me, anybody, who know or implement that.
THANKS
VIJAY